# I need help about Title in sweetalert

Tags: sweetalert2

I have an error (or nothing shows) on put a Text with quotes when I refer to inches ( " or ´´)

```
swal({
    text: ' Product X 10" '
})
```

or

```
swal({
    text: ' Product X 10' '
})
```

What might be the cause of this?

Comment: First of all, if you are using the latest version of swal (8.x.x) you need to use `swal.fire()` to launch a sweetalert pop-up. I tried your first example and works fine for me. The second causes an error (you have an unterminated string). As an advice, have a look to the browser console to check why swal is not shown.

Comment: Thanks for answer me, my swal ver. is 7.20.7 and the console error saids: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

Comment: It works perfectly for me, look at https://shore-roast.glitch.me/